# RowReduce: Solving for the resource vector (a, b, c) in Augmented Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra

Here are two examples:

```
RowReduce[{{3, 1, a}, {2, 1, b}}]
```

evaluates to

```
{{1, 0, a - b}, {0, 1, -2 a + 3 b}}
```

but

```
RowReduce[{{1, 2, 3, a}, {4, 5, 6, b}, {7, 8, 9, c}}]
```

evaluates to

```
{{1, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

The result is independent of `a`, `b` and `c`.

Since I want to know the steps of reduction, I add `a`, `b` and `c` for bookkeeping.
But it does not work in the second example.
Is anything wrong or is any way to keep track of the steps of reduction?

Comment: Here's a hint: `Solve[{x + 2 y + 3 z == a, 4 x + 5 y + 6 z == b, 7 x + 8 y + 9 z == c}, {x, y, z}]` results in `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your ultimate goal is a record of all of the row operations required to put a matrix in [reduced row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) or if you want to figure out for what right-hand sides $\mathbf{b}=(a,b,c)$ does $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ have a solution.

For the latter,

```
RowReduce[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}]
```

which results in

```
{{1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

Thus, $z$ is a free variable, $y=-2z$, and $x=z$. So only right-hand sides of the form $\mathbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}d$ where $d$ is any constant will work.

For the former, that is a different conversation altogether. The [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) of $A$ deals with this.

Comment: Thanks JohnD 
I think I try to solve something like
x+2y+3z==Integers
4x+5y+6z==Integers
7x+8y+9z==Integers

I do the Gaussian elimination without normalizing the leading coefficient in each row to 1 and get
{{1,2,3},{0,-3,-6},{0,0,0}}
So I will have 
x+2y+3z==Integers
3(y+2z)==Integers

But
RowReduce[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}]
will result in
{{1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 0, 0}}
That is why I include {a,b,c} to keep track to the multiplicative constants.

Do you know how to do rowreduce without normalizing each equation or ways to solve equations up to integers by mathematica?

Comment: So you want to solve equations where the *right-hand side* is constrained to integer values or when the *unknowns* (here, $x,y,z$) are constrained to integer values?

Comment: The right-hand side is integer valued. No constraints on variables.

Comment: Well, from the answer above, $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ is only solvable for right-hand sides of the form $\mathbf{b}=(1,-2,1)d$, $d\in\mathbb{R}$. So if you only want integer right-hand sides, take $d\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If you want to work over the integers use **HermiteDecomposition** instead of **RowReduce**. Your example: {uu, hh} = HermiteDecomposition[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}]

{{{1, 0, 0}, {4, -1, 0}, {1, -2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 6}, {0, 0, 
   0}}} The first part of the result gives the transformation matrix.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks Daniel. I wasn't familiar with this tool, but it is good to know!

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is very old, but I stumbled across it while working on a similar problem and thought this might be of some use to someone in the future.

I think the OP intended the given matrix

`{{1, 2, 3, a}, {4, 5, 6, b}, {7, 8, 9, c}}`

to be taken as an *augmented* matrix with reduced row echelon form

`{{1, 0, -1, 1/3 (-5 a + 2 b)}, {0, 1, 2, 1/3 (4 a - b)}, {0, 0, 0, a - 2 b + c}}`

But

`RowReduce[{{1, 2, 3, a}, {4, 5, 6, b}, {7, 8, 9, c}}]`

knows nothing of the augmentation and continues the reduction by taking `a - 2 b + c` as the next pivot and gives

`{{1, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}`

### A Workaround (Add a "Dummy" Column Vector)

A workaround that I came up with is to just add a "dummy" column vector `Transpose[{{0, 0, 1}}]` to the augmented matrix in the next-to-last column to absorb the pivot. Then

```
R = RowReduce[{{1, 2, 3, 0, a}, {4, 5, 6, 0, b}, {7, 8, 9, 1, c}}]
```

gives

```
{{1, 0, -1, 0, 1/3 (-5 a + 2 b)}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 1/3 (4 a - b)}, {0, 0, 0, 1, a - 2 b + c}}
```

You can then either simply ignore the dummy column in the result or, if desired, do

```
Drop[R, None, {-2}]
```

which gives

```
{{1, 0, -1, 1/3 (-5 a + 2 b)}, {0, 1, 2, 1/3 (4 a - b)}, {0, 0, 0, a - 2 b + c}}
```