# How to define an `MatrixReduce` function that can reduce the symbol matrix to the simplest type

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

The `RowReduce` function of MMA [can not effectively reduce](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227929/how-to-solve-this-equation-with-rank-relation-of-matrix) the matrix with parameters to the row simplest type.

```
   RowReduce[{{1, a, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}]
```

The row simplest form of matrix $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$ should be $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & a-2 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ instead of $\left(\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$.

Moreover, MMA also lacks a built-in function that transforms a symbol matrix into the simplest type through elementary row and column transformations.

How to write these custom functions which are widely used in linear algebra? If you can, I also need a user-defined function to judge the rank of the symbol matrix (output the discussion results according to the variable value range).

**In addition,** I don't know if the simplest form (it is obtained by elementary row transformation and column transformation) of a symbolic matrix is the same as Smith transformation.

```
A = {{1, 2, a}, {1, 3, 0}, {2, 7, -a}};
B = {{1, a, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}};
Control`PCS`SmithForm[A, a]
Control`PCS`SmithForm[B, a]
```

But the Smith canonical form of matrix `A` is independent of `a`, which is a little different from the simplest form of matrix `A`.

Comment: Read [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29440/72682) and use the LUDecomposition technique there. This gives me: `{{1, a, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 2 - a}}`. I also looked around for a `ResourceFunction` and found these, though they don't solve your problem directly: `rsb = ResourceFunction["RowSpaceBasis"]
csb = ResourceFunction["ColumnSpaceBasis"];
pvc = ResourceFunction["PivotColumns"];`

Comment: @flinty Thank you very much, but `ResourceFunction["RowSpaceBasis"][{{1, a, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}]` still returns an identity matrix, which is not the row simplest form of matrix `{{1, a, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}`.