# Why row reduce doesn't "act symbolically" on square matrices?

Tags: matrix

Suppose I do the following:

> [image]

Now, If I compute:

> [image]

Then "Mathematica stops being symbolic". Why does this happen? I want the computation to show matrix entries in terms of $a,b,c,d$, similar to the first example. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I'm not even sure how Mathematica "knows" this. After all, what if `b == e == 0`? You'd hope the symbolic result would hold for all values of `a`, `b`, `d`, `e`, but it seems Mathematica's making some hidden assumptions at some point.

Comment: For that matter, why does `MatrixRank[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]` give `2`...

Comment: What specific different result did you expect?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It should be something like: $$\begin{pmatrix}
{c}&{d}\\ 
{0}&{\frac{bc-ad}{c}}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Symbolic computations in Mathematica are often generically correct, meaning that the results ignore excepts on a locus of codimension ≥ 1. Even the first result is wrong if `b == 2 a`. I don't really see a big difference between the two examples.

Comment: That's not what `RowReduce` does. Which puts the question outside the scope of the forum.

Comment: Surely Mathemtica ought to return a conditional result from `RowReduce`, etc., for such a symbolic matrix?

Comment: @murray No. That's not what it is designed to do. It works over the field of rational functions in the variables present. See also [this previous MSE thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29433/rowreduce-for-symbolic-matrices) (for which the present thread is essentially a duplicate). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179454/assumptions-in-mathematicas-nullspace-command-for-symbolic-matrices/6179478). And [this too](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38160/rowreduce-record-of-all-the-row-operations-for-rref) might be relevant.

Answer (score 5):

This gives the weird result in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242481/why-row-reduce-doesnt-act-symbolically-on-square-matrices#comment611895_242481) that has nothing to do with the matrix `{{a, b}, {d, e}}` in the question:

```
LinearSolve[{{c, d}, {a, b}}]@"getU" // Together
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The matrix may be obtained from `LUDecomposition[mat]` as well.

Comment: This is really what I have been looking for! Could you explain what is the `@getU`?

Comment: @BillyRubina It gets the "U" matrix of the LU decomposition, which is the result of Gaussian elimination. The "U" stands for upper triangular matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Check:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

And from the documentation for RowReduce:
RowReduce performs a version of Gaussian elimination, adding multiples of rows together so as to produce zero elements when possible. The final matrix is in reduced row echelon form.
If m is a non-degenerate square matrix, RowReduce[m] is IdentityMatrix[Length[m]].