# RowReduce : Record of all the row operations for RREF

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I read ["for what right-hand sides $b=(a,b,c)$ does $Ax=b$ have a solution"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16281/9983), but that question pertains to solving for the unknown vector. I'd like a record of all of the row operations required to put a matrix in reduced row echelon form without LU Decomposition.

When I input `RowReduce[{{3, 1, a}, {2, 1, b}}]`, Mathematica returns:
`{{1, 0, a - b}, {0, 1, -2 a + 3 b}}`

Howbeit, when I input RowReduce[{{1, 2, r_1}, {2, 3, r_2}, {2, 4, r_3}, {2, 5, r_4}}], Mathematica doesn't manifest explicitly the resource vector $(r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4)$ in : 
`{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}` ? 

 How can I oblige it to, whenever matrices are input and not only for this one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148/131

Comment: To get full information you might augment with an identity matrix, then row reduce. `mat = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}};
augmat = Join[mat, IdentityMatrix[Length[mat]], 2];
RowReduce[augmat]`